Movie with a young boy who doesnt talk but you can hear his thoughts through out the movie
I know that there are atleast 2 parts of the movie in the first one there was just the boy and in the second one he gets a baby sister. You can here both their thoughts all the time and i think in the second part the house burns and the boy saves the baby sister. The father his job is something with flying but im not sure. and maybe im mixing things up now but I think there was a weird green guy somewhere in the movie? I saw it when I was about 8 or something and its rather a comedy movie please help me this has been bothering me since a while xD 

When were you 8?

Look Who's Talking (boy is born) and Look Who's Talking Too (sister is born). There was also a second sequel, Look Who's Talking Now, with their pet dogs.

The romantic ups and downs of accountant Mollie Jensen (Kirstie Alley) are viewed cynically by a most unusual bystander -- her talking newborn, Mikey (Bruce Willis). She becomes pregnant through an affair with a married man, Albert (George Segal), and then counts on the friendship of taxi driver James (John Travolta) once she discovers Albert is a lying cad. Although Mikey likes James, and James cares for both the baby and Mollie, she isn't sure she can settle down with a blue-collar boyfriend. [Google Synopsis for "Look Who's Talking"]

James becomes a pilot in the second movie.
